# If a user is allowed to create a bounty they should be allowed to comment even if their reputation goes below 50

Tags: feature-request, comments, bounty

I used 100 reputation to create a bounty on a question, but this put my reputation at 41. I could not comment in any way on the responses I received because my reputation did not allow me to comment. Either a user should not be allowed to go below 50 when posting a bounty, or the rule should be broken for that post. I know this is a corner case, but it was very frustrating as a user who gave reputation to get an answer, when the answer was more on the right track but still not a complete answer to the problem.

Comment: "the rule should be broken for that post" That's not possible.

Comment: Perhaps I should say "a rule should be made allowing the bounty provider to comment on all posts they have posted bounties for regardless of reputation."  It is software. If you can think it, you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feature request makes sense, and it has already been proposed on Meta Stack Exchange: [Allow bounty owners to comment on questions they've placed a bounty on, even if they have less than 50 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246684/295232). It has been put on [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) May this year, so perhaps it could be resolved soon.